# How is this blocking thread call "freeing" itself?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I'm running a basic single threaded application.

Normally, when calling `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show()`, one would expect this call to effectively block further execution until this method had returned.

However, when using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, it seems the ***same*** thread is somehow freeing itself and the `Timer`'s `Tick` event is firing on this same thread.

What on earth is going on? I have a feeling this may have something to do with threading apartments, but I'd like some clarification.

Recreated in it's simplest form as a Console Application as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program();
        while (true)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }

    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;

    public Program()
    {
        timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 2000 };
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

   private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Thread {0} has entered", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)); 
        var result = MessageBox.Show("Test");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Thread {0} has left", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)); 
    }
}
```

Output:

> Thread 10 has entered
>   Thread 10 has entered
>   Thread 10 has entered
>   Thread 10 has entered
>   Thread 10 has entered

Comment: That isn't a good test program because calling `Application.DoEvents()` will give precisely this behaviour. Can you reproduce it with a simple Windows Forms app?

Comment: I'm only calling this in my short example as this is what a default winforms app will do.

Comment: A default winforms app will NOT call `Application.DoEvents()`

Comment: Create a Winforms app, stick a Winforms Timer on it and you will observe the exact same behaviour.

Comment: Indeed, but I was just pointing out that a console app calling Application.DoEvents() is not an equivalent test.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I used this example which uses `DoEvents()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That's a really bad example from Microsoft - you should never use `Application.DoEvents()`. If you are, it means you have a design problem IMHO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97610/discussion-between-maxp-and-matthew-watson).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a modal window such as a message box is displayed, the Windows message pump continues to run.

If it didn't, the display of the window behind the modal window wouldn't be updated as you move the modal window around in front of it.

Because Windows messages are still being pumped, the "WM_TIMER" messages will still be sent to the non-foreground window and hence you will see the behaviour you have noted.

The key thing to note is that a Windows timer causes Windows to post "WM_TIMER" messages into the window's event queue, and as long as the window's message pump is running, the timer events will continue to be handled.

One common way to avoid this re-entrancey issue is to disable the timer while handling the tick.

For example, put your tick handling code into a method called `handleTimer()` and then handle the tick like this:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Enabled = false;

    try
    {
        handleTimer();
    }

    finally 
    {
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

(You might want to not re-enable the timer in the event of an exception, in which case you won't need  the `try/finally` logic above.)

Comment: There isn't such a thing as a 'same-thread' lock, so is there a way one can block such repetition other than manually using a `bool` to block manually?

Comment: @maxp What I usually do is to call `timer.Enabled = false;` as the very first thing in the handler, and then `timer.Enabled = true;` as the very last thing. I'll add that to my answer.